# Linked List/Node Clas - Adding User Input to Linked List

Tags: c#, linked-list, nodes, user-input

I have the user inputting a string which is stored in the variable 'word'. I now want to add this stored variable to the linked list. I've tried using

`LinkedList<string>.Add(word);`

To add the variable to the linked this but it isn't working and is returning the error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'LinkedList.Add(string)"

I'm assuming it has something to do with my linked list but I'm not to sure.

Any help or ideas on the issue would be great.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace project
{
    public class LinkedList<TData>
    {

        private Node<TData> head;
        private int count;

        public LinkedList(string word)
        {
            this.head = null;
            this.count = 0;
        }

        public bool Empty
        {
            get { return this.count == 0; }
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return this.count; }
        }

        public TData this[int index]
        {
            get { return this.Get(index); }
        }

        public TData Add(int index, TData data)
        {
            if (index < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Index: " + index);

            if (index > count)
                index = count;

            Node<TData> current = this.head;

            if (this.Empty || index == 0)
            {
                this.head = new Node<TData>(data, this.head);
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++)
                {
                    current = current.Next;
                    current.Next = new Node<TData>(data, current.Next);
                }
            }
            count++;
            return data;
        }

        public TData Add(TData data)
        {
            return this.Add(count, data);
        }

        public TData Remove(int index)
        {
            if (index < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Index: " + index);

            if (this.Empty)
                return default(TData);

            if (index >= this.count)
                index = count - 1;

            Node<TData> current = this.head;
            TData result;

            if (index == 0)
            {
                result = current.Data;
                this.head = current.Next;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; index < index - 1; i++) ;
                current = current.Next;
                result = current.Next.Data;
                current.Next = current.Next.Next;
            }

            count--;

            return result;

        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            this.head = null;
            this.count = 0;
        }

        public int IndexOf(TData data)
        {
            Node<TData> current = this.head;

            for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++)
            {
                if (current.Data.Equals(data))
                    return i;

                current = current.Next;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        public bool Contains(TData data)
        {
            return this.IndexOf(data) >= 0;
        }

        public TData Get(int index)
        {
            if (index < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Index: " + index);

            if (this.Empty)
                return default(TData);

            if (index >= this.count)
                index = this.count - 1;

            Node<TData> current = this.head;

            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
                current = current.Next;

            return current.Data;
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace project
{
    public class Node<TData>
    {

        private Node<TData> next { get; set; }

        public Node(TData data, Node<TData> next)
        {
            this.Data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }

        public TData Data { get; set; }

        public Node<TData> Next
        {
            get { return this.next; }
            set { this.next = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace project
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string word;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a word");
            word = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("You typed: " + word);
            Console.ReadKey();

            var list = new LinkedList<string>(word);

            LinkedList<string>.Add(word);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
        var list = new LinkedList<string>(word);

        LinkedList<string>.Add(word);
```

To this:

```
        var list = new LinkedList<string>();

        list.Add(word);
```

`list` is your linked list object in memory. Whenever you want to do something with your list, you use the variable reference `list`, not the name for the *kind* of object it is. The reason we use the name of the variable rather than the name of the kind is because we might very well want to have two or more of them in our program:

```
        var postiveList = new LinkedList<string>();
        var negativeList = new LinkedList<string>();

        positiveList.Add("happy");
        negativeList.Add("sad");
```

It's only possible to use the name of the type(kind), when you're using something declared as *static* - and nothing in your program is static that I can point to and make a suitable demonstration of. Something you'll have probably used though:

```
        int x = Convert.ToInt32("1234");
```

Convert here is static, the name of a type of class. You don't need to make a new Convert before you use it, and you can't have (nor need) more than one Convert in a program, so it makes sense to have it be static (only one of them)

Some things are both static and not:

```
var startTime = new DateTime(1970,1,1);
var endTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

`startTime` and `endTime` are both instances of a DateTime. To get the end time, however, we used a static property `UtcNow` of the DateTime type. It created a new DateTime for us based on the value of the computer clock and returned it. We didn't need for any other datetime to exist before we did this. If it helps, think of these static things as being like factories that churn out manufactured objects on demand. There is only one factory, and the things it makes are always the same kind of thing but it can make millions of them

---

Also change this:

```
    public LinkedList(string word)
    {
        this.head = null;
        this.count = 0;
    }
```

To this:

```
    public LinkedList()
    {
        this.head = null;
        this.count = 0;
    }
```

There's no point asking for something and then not doing anything with it - it just makes the thing that asks harder to use. I get the feeling you didn't write LinkedList, but you might have added this in while trying to get a word into it

Comment: Yeah I didn't write the LinkedList and yes it was added when I was trying to get the word into it, thanks for the help it solved the issue. How would I go about printing this list to the screen now? 
 ```         
foreach(string str in list) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(str); 
        }
 ```
I assume this should do the trick ?

Comment: For that to work out your class would have to be enumerable (implement the IEnumerable interface)

Comment: I'd love to say that's heplful but I have no idea about that at all, what would be the best way to display it to the console or does the "IEnumberable interface" need to be implemented for me to do so ?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/571139/foreach-on-ienumerable - you can't say, right now, "foreach var item in list" because for that code to work C# needs to know how to get something that it can call "next next next" on to step through it.. If you implement the IEnumerable interface then it will mean C# can treat your object like "some enumerable thing" - it will call Next, you'll give it the next thing in the list etc

Comment: Thank's I'll take a look at it and hopefully I can work my head around it, slowly going insane looking at the code.

Comment: Well.. System.Collections.Generic does already have a LinkedList but I get that the aim of this exercise is probably academic so rolling your own rather than using Microsoft's.. In some years to come you'll be lookinga t it and going "what was I worried about?" - it just takes some time to sink in (like anything, really)

Comment: Your spot on, indeed it just takes some time but I don't have alot of time to play with.

Comment: Incidentally, the earlier note was a tiny bit misleading. When I said "doesn't implement IEnumerable" it's not exactly *mandatory* that it does. Strictly speaking, in order to be `foreach`able, a class has to have a method called `GetEnumerator()` and that method can return *anything* that has a method `MoveNext()` and a `Current` property. If you implement IEnumerable then you *must* provide a `GetEnumerator()` method that returns something that implements IEnumerator, and in order to implement IEnumerator a class *must* have a `MoveNext()`  and a `Current`..

Comment: Thanks for the help man but I can't even begin to process it, everything is going in one ear and out the other feel like I'm in a code block lol

Comment: IEnumerable and IEnumerator came along separately to those rules of "to be foreachable, a thing must have GetEnumerator that returns something with MoveNext() and Current" though they essentially ratify/standardize the behavior into a couple of interfaces so  if you implement the interfaces you can be sure that you're all good.. But it's not quite accurate to say "must implement interface X", it's more accurate to say "must have a, b and c by convention but if you implement interface X then they surely will have the necessary a, b and c" - subtle difference

Answer (score 0):

you write:

```
LinkedList<string>.Add(word);
```

This is an attempt to call a static method `Add` on the type `LinkedList<string>`. And the compiler is telling you that this is a *instance* method and not a *static* method. I.e. you want to call:

```
list.Add(word);
```

Also, the constructor

```
public LinkedList(string word)
```

takes a string, but does not do anything with it. This parameter should probably be removed.